# How to tag bookmarks in Chrome with xmarks

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, tags, xmarks

I am using Xmarks to store my Bookmarks & access them across all the devices I use.

Lately I started using Google Chrome as my Default Browser, now there is Xmarks Addon available for Chrome but it does't allow you to add Tags to the bookmarks, although Xmarks has the ability to tag the bookmarks.

I am open to other options, but I want my bookmarks to be tagged, & I can access it across all the Devices & Browsers I use.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Where you able to accomplish this? If so, would you mind posting your answer here?

Answer (score -1):

So i think that if you set up a browser with the bookmarks as you want them - I used Firefox, because I like the tags and I like their built in BM mgr.  Set it all up and EXPORT A BACKUP!  If you don't do that you might get burned!

Ok then sync to xmarks.

Open Chrome. Make sure you install Bookmarks Tagging.  I have like three tag programs extended on Chrome, not sure which does the trick but web searches seem to indicate "Bookmark Tagging" is the magic one.

When you open Chrome xmarks will let you sync, download or cancel.  Download, if you set bookmark tagging up already.

This is what I did.  And I synced from Chrome, just to be check, and so far all my tags are intact.  Not sure if that will change, but I got my backup so I'm happy.

Worst case, you can set it so Chrome doesnt sync.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Rather than reading the tags from the imported bookmarks, it turned the folder structure into tags. That's useful, but not what I need.